# How to check if ppp connection is busy

Tags: python, linux, debian, ppp

To look at some details regarding a **ppp** connection, one can run the following command:

```
$ ifconfig ppp
ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:197.108.58.82  P-t-P:10.64.64.64  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:479 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:479 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:68118 (68.1 KB)  TX bytes:32771 (32.7 KB)
```

In order to check if there is any data transfer, one can re-run that command, while paying attention to **RX packets** and **TX packets** to see if there is a change (maybe there's a better way of doing this?).

Anyways, I could do the same with Python, but it's cumbersome (using **subprocess**, and then parsing the output), so am wondering if there's a better way. I would have loved to use [**netifaces**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces) for this, but it provides more limited info:

```
$ python -c "import netifaces; print netifaces.ifaddresses('ppp0')"
{2: [{'peer': '10.64.64.64', 'netmask': '255.255.255.255', 'addr': '197.108.58.82'}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can look up the data in `/proc`, if that is easier than invoking `ifconfig`.

```
def GetPacketCount(dev_name):
    '''Return (received_packets, transmitted_packets) for network device dev_name'''
    with open('/proc/net/dev') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            line = line.split()
            if line[0].startswith(dev_name):
                return int(line[2]), int(line[10])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    print GetPacketCount(sys.argv[1])
```

ref: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt